# How to convert a CPoint object into a string?

Tags: c++, mfc, type-conversion

I have a `std::array` of CPoint objects which I want to output in an mfc application:

```
std::array<CPoint,11> v = pDoc->m_ElementList.back();

    for(int j=0;   j < v.size();  j++ )
        aDC.TextOutW(x+=3,y+=3, _T(v[n++]));
```

Now `_T(v[n++])` obviously doesn't work since it's a CPoint object, not a string. How can I output CPoint objects in this way? Or how can I convert them into strings to use them in such a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CString s;
CPoint p;

s.Format("x=%d / y=%d",p.x,p.y);
```

For a std::string use either `sprintf` or a `std::stringstream`.

```
stringstream ss;
ss << "x=" << p.x << "/" << "y=" << "p.y";
```

Comment: It's a `std::string` not a `CString` object, so it doesn't have a Format() function

Comment: @Ghost - The TextOutW function will work with a CString or a std::string, or anything else that can be converted to a *wchar.  The important point the answer is that CPoint does not have any string conversions. You must convert the x an y members of the CPoint into some string representation.  You control the formatting.

Comment: @Ghost - It makes the code easier to read and easier to get correct if you do that formatting into a separate variable, instead of trying to do an in-line conversion inside the argument list of TextOutW

Comment: @ Mark Taylor Thanks guys, now this is what I've done according to what you've told me:  `s.Format("x=%d / y=%d",v[n].x, v[n++].y);`  But still I get the error " no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list"

Comment: @Ghost, use `L"x=..."` to get a wide string for the first argument, or `_T("...")` to use the Microsoft helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `CPoint` is or can do but I think you have to write something like:

```
std::wstring to_wstring(const CPoint& point)
{
  #ifdef HAS_CPP11
  using std::to_wstring;
  return to_wstring(point.x) + L"; " + to_wstring(point.y);
  #else
  std::wstringstream s;
  s << point.x << L"; " << point.y;
  return s.str();
  #endif
}

std::string to_string(const CPoint& point)
{
  /*..*/
}
```

Comment: okay so this is want I've done: 
`std::string a = std::to_string(v[n++].x) + "; " +  std::to_string(v[n++].y);` 
But I'm getting an error saying "More than one instance of the overloaded function matches the argument list" - now what?

Comment: Seems that your std lib has no overload of `std::to_string` for the type of `CPoint::x`. What is your vc version and what type is `CPoint::x`?